# How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to 16}\sqrt[4]{x} = 2$ by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt[4]{x}$ and let $L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 16}f(x)$.

If $\epsilon=1$, I'm supposed to find the largest $\delta$ such that

$$\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$$

whenever

$$0 < \vert x - 16 \vert < \delta \space \space \space (*)$$

I know that $L=2$, so I unpack the definition of

$$\vert \sqrt[4]{x}-2 \vert < \epsilon=1$$

and want to find the $\delta$ that makes this true when $(*)$ holds.

Comment: Maybe you were explicitly asked this but it's worth noting that finding a largest $\delta$ is rarely (never in my experience) necessary

Comment: Hint: You want $1=2-\epsilon<\sqrt[4]x<3=2+\epsilon$ if $16-\delta<x<16+\delta.$

Comment: You could use $\delta=15,$ for example.

Comment: Essentially, you only need that $\sqrt[4]x$ is increasing and has an inverse function.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Suppose that $|x - 16| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$:

\begin{align*}
|\sqrt[4]{x} - 2| & = \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - 4}{\sqrt[4]{x} + 2}\right|\\\\
& \leq \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - 4}{2}\right|\\\\
& = \left|\frac{x - 16}{2(\sqrt{x} + 4)}\right|\\\\
& \leq \left|\frac{x - 16}{8}\right|\\\\
& < \frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{8} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?